# php doesnt show error

Tags: php, linux, opensuse

im working in php on suse11.0 my problem is when i type a wrong syntax or query it doesnt show error only blank page shown at this situtaion

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 8):

You might to configure [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) ([see also](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)), and enable the displaying of errors (see [`display_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) or [ini_set](http://php.net/ini_set)) -- at least on your development machine

In your php.ini file, you'd use

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
display_errors = On
html_errors = On
```

Or, in your PHP code :

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

You might also want to install [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) on your development box, to get nice [stacktraces](http://xdebug.org/docs/stack_trace) wehn an error / exception occurs

Of course, on your production machine, you probably don't want to display errors ; so that will have to be configured depending on your environment ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It is almost certainly the case that `display_errors` is disabled in php.ini.

This is a good thing on product servers, and makes development systems basically unusable.

For a development system you probably want to add one of these lines to you php.ini file:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

or

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
```

Comment: To add to this, you can probably find the errors in the webserver's log (for Apache, this is often /var/log/httpd/error_log)

Answer (score 2):

Create a file for example test.php with this content:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Execute it in your browser and search where the php.ini file is located.
Than turn error reporting and displaying errors in php.ini on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure error_reporting is turned on in php.ini

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in you php.ini file that display_errors is on and set error_reporting to E_ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Start your script with:

```
<?php
    ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers do answer your question, I just wanted to point out that it is best to provide your own error checking routine (or code) so that your script will show pleasant error messages to users.
something like

```
$result=@mysql_query($some_query);
if(!$result){
   if($debugging==TRUE){
       echo($some_query.'<br>'.mysql_error());//shows error in debugging mode
    }
   else{
     log_error()// error logging function
      die( 'there was a problem with your request the problem has been logged and we are working on it');//or something like that

   }
}
//no error
more code
```