# Change Debug build to On PHP

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, php

How do I change the Debug build to On in lamp stack environment?

[image: phpinfo screen shot]

Comment: What does **Debug Build** do?

Comment: I have Debug build **off** but i can see all PHP errors. Enabling **display_errors** to **On**. Are you sure you're looking for correct variable?

Comment: I can't see any! ...wonder what's missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php doesnt show error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246634/php-doesnt-show-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i said in the comments you need to enable `display_errors` instead of *Debug build*.

Goto your `php.ini`

From terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

Search for the option `display_errors` (not the already commented option, means jump to second search result)

Change from **Off** to **On**

```
display_errors = On
```

Also enable these options as well as you may need in future

```
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
```