# Mkdir do not create folder and no Errors shown. (PHP)

Tags: php, mkdir

I need some help with mkdir in my .php file. It's not creating the directory.

I'm currently running Centos 6.6 web server, I have all folders chmod 755 and owner = Apache.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
   $rand_dir_name = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 15);
   mkdir("../userdata/profile_pics/".$rand_dir_name);
?>
```

No error messages are shown and I'm 100% sure that the path /userdata/profile_pics exists.

Any help?

Comment: maybe you should try

mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../userdata/profile_pics/".$rand_dir_name);

Comment: @Yair.R Nope, that didn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: print what $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/../userdata/profile_pics/".$rand_dir_name gives you and make sure that this is the correct path

Comment: also, the mkdir method returns boolean result. tell me if it returned true or false.

Comment: How exactly do I print it? I'm quite new to php

Comment: do var_dump(mkdir(....));
and paste here

Comment: @Yair.R Here it is: Notice: Undefined variable: rand_dir_name in /var/www/milburr.com/public_html/dump.php on line 3 Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in /var/www/milburr.com/public_html/dump.php on line 3 bool(false)

Comment: well you see the errors, you have to fix it.. $rand_dir_name is undefined

Comment: Got that fixed now. All I'm left with now is: Warning: mkdir(): No such file or directory in /var/www/milburr.com/public_html/dump.php on line 5 bool(false)

Comment: Try clearstatcache();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mkdir("../userdata/profile_pics/".$rand_dir_name, 0777, true);
```

There is also a chance you're in a wrong directory currently. If this is the case - you need to change the current dir with chdir() or specify the full path

Comment: Alright. I think I'm getting closer to the answer. Right now it's saying permission denied. The thing is, I made apache the owner of the public_html folder, and also used chmod 0777 on the folder. I don't get why it's still saying permission denied.

Comment: make sure that the folders userdata and profile_pics are also chmos 0777

Comment: Done that. This time I used the full path " mkdir("/var/www/milburr.com/public_html/userdata/profile_pics/".$rand_dir_name, 0777, true);  ". It generated the folders var, www, milburr.com, public _html etc. inside the original public_html folder.. Something going wrong here..

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the permissions to 777, that is a security problem as it gives read and write access to the world. It may be that your apache user does not have read/write permissions on the directory.

Here's what you do in Ubuntu

Make sure all files are owned by the Apache group and user. In Ubuntu it is the www-data group and user

chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/webserver/www

Next enabled all members of the www-data group to read and write files

chmod -R g+rw /path/to/webserver/www

The php mkdir() function should now work without returning errors

Comment: Alright. So I have that working now on my dump.php file I made. It created the folder in the right place. Now the issue is that it doesn't work when I paste the exact same code inside the original file I'm using. It has the exact same rights.

Comment: is the original file in the same folder as dump.php file? if not, thats the problem.

Comment: Yeah, it is. I really have no clue why this is not working.

Comment: if you say that in dump.php file works so there is something in the original file that interrups. So start commenting lines in the original file until it starts to work and see what was the problem. Anyways this question is solved since mkdir now works in other files at the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Check your display error settings in php.ini (default they are disabled for the production environment). The solution [php doesnt show error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246634/php-doesnt-show-error)

Comment: Besides an error about timezone nothing is shown. I read about a lot of people having a permissions error, I'm not seeing that either.

Comment: Try execute your file from CLI: "$ php your_file_name.php" and see result

Comment: That didn't work. Just says command not found.

Comment: type in command line "php your_file_name.php". PHP have to be.