# I get 500 in production environment without any logs

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I am using `Symfony 3` on `CentOS 7` with `Apache 2.4` and `PHP 5.6`.

With the dev server all works fine but when I switch to `Apache 2.4` I can't make the production environment working. The strange thing is that calling `dev_app.php` works OK. And even stranger is that I see no logs! Just in the `access.log` I got:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [05/Sep/2017:22:35:28 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
```

Here is how I defined the virtual server:

```
<VirtualHost *:9002>
    ServerName test.something.com
    DocumentRoot "/data/site/web"

    <Directory "/data/site/web">
        Require all granted

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    <Directory /data/site/web/vendor>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /data/site/app/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /data/site/app/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500.. indicates there's a PHP error. You can turn on PHP error reporting as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246634/php-doesnt-show-error and see if that turns up any results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I would check permission for that file.

`sudo chmod 644 /data/site/app/logs/error.log`

2. Check owner on /data/site/web folder

`sudo chown -R www-data /data/site/web`

or another solution is to show errors on web like

```
<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", "1");
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. The owner of the error.log file was root as well as the access.log. But since PHP is running in fast-cgi mode under apache user, I guess it couldn't write the error. But I wonder my Symfony didn't detect it and logged it? (I had forgotten to specify the port number in pramaters.yml)

Answer (score 1):

clear your cache in prod env `php bin/console cache:clear --no-warmup --env=prod` then `php bin/console cache:warmup --env=prod`